# c stack (using dynamic array) realloc memory leak problem

Tags: c, data-structures, stack, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int LENGTH = 1;
int TOP = -1;

void push(char**, char);
char pop(char*);
char peek(char*);
int isEmpty();
int isFull();

void convertToRPN(char*, char*, char*);
int isOperator(char);
int getPrecedence(char);


int main(void) {
    char* stack = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * LENGTH);
    if (!stack) {
        printf("Memory allocation failed./n");
        exit(1);
    }

    char expression[100];
    printf("Enter the mathematical expression: ");
    scanf("%s", expression);

    char rpn[100];
    convertToRPN(expression, stack, rpn);

    printf("The rpn: %s\n", rpn);

    free(stack);

    return 0;
}


int isOperator(char c) {
    return (c == '+' || c == '-' || c == '*' || c == '/');
}


int getPrecedence(char c) {
    if (c == '+' || c == '-')
        return 1;
    if (c == '*' || c == '/')
        return 2;
    return 0; 
}


void convertToRPN(char *expression, char* stack, char* rpn) {
    
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; expression[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (expression[i] >= '0' && expression[i] <= '9') {
            rpn[j] = expression[i];
            j++;
        } else if (isOperator(expression[i])) {
            while (!isEmpty() && peek(stack) != '(' && getPrecedence(peek(stack)) >= getPrecedence(expression[i])) {
                rpn[j] = pop(stack);
                j++;
            }
            push(&stack, expression[i]);
        } else if (expression[i] == '(') {
            push(&stack, expression[i]);
        } else if (expression[i] == ')') {
            while (!isEmpty() && peek(stack) != '(') {
                rpn[j] = pop(stack);
                j++;
            }
            pop(stack);
        } else {
            printf("Unsupported character.\n");
            exit(2);
        }
    }

    while (!isEmpty()) {
        rpn[j] = pop(stack);
        j++;
    }

    rpn[j] = '\0';
}


void push(char **stack, char c) {
    if (isFull()) {
        *stack = (char *)realloc(*stack, sizeof(char) * (LENGTH + 1));
        if (!*stack) {
            printf("Memory reallocation failed.\n");
            exit(5);
        }
        LENGTH++;
    }
    TOP++;
    (*stack)[TOP] = c;
}


char pop(char *stack) {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        printf("POP: the stack is empty.\n");
        exit(3);
    } else {
        char item = stack[TOP];
        TOP--;
        return item;
    }
}


char peek(char *stack) {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        printf("PEEK: the stack is empty.\n");
        exit(4);
    }
    return stack[TOP];
}


int isEmpty() {
    return TOP == -1;
}


int isFull() {
    return TOP == LENGTH - 1;
}
```

This code performs RPN (Reverse Polish notation) conversion, but gives definite lost in  1 block.
According to valgrind the code has a memory leak issue.The message is cryptic, but I guess it's in realloc().
Maybe to help the message:

Enter the mathematical expression: 5+9+2*1
The rpn: 59+21*+

Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
at 0x484810F: free
by 0x1092FE: main (exer1_2.c:34)
Address 0x4a78040 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 1 free'd
at 0x484ABC0: realloc
by 0x109616: push (exer1_2.c:92)
by 0x1094BB: convertToRPN
by 0x1092D4: main
Block was alloc'd at
at 0x4845828: malloc
by 0x109256: main

HEAP SUMMARY:
in use at exit: 2 bytes in 1 blocks
total heap usage: 4 allocs, 4 frees, 2,051 bytes allocated

LEAK SUMMARY:
definitely lost: 2 bytes in 1 blocks
indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks

ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)

Overall i guess the problem is about my implementation of the stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in the program. The pointer `stack` is passed to the function `convertToRPN` by value

```
void convertToRPN(char*, char*, char*);

//...

convertToRPN(expression, stack, rpn);
```

So the function deals with a copy of the value of the original pointer. The original pointer stays unchanged. As a result the pointer has an invalid value and this call of `free` in `main`

```
free(stack);
```

does not free the memory allocated during execution of the function `convertToRPN`.

You should at least pass the pointer by reference to the function through a pointer to it. That is the function should be declared and called like

```
void convertToRPN(char*, char**, char*);

//...

convertToRPN(expression, &stack, rpn);
```

though it would be better if neither memory for the stack was allocated in `main`. The stack is used in the function `convertToRPN` where memory should be allocated and freed.

And it would be better to declare a structure Stack like for example

```
struct Stack
{
    size_t top;
    size_t size;  
    char *mem;
};
```

and use an object of the structure instead of several separate variables. And it is a very bad idea to use global variables

```
int LENGTH = 1;
int TOP = -1;
```

I advise you to redesign the code.